# override GetAll to change Sort - example required

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to override an `AsyncCrudAppService` call - "GetAll" in order to change the returned sort order.

[image]

Firstly, is overriding the method, in fact, the correct way to do this?
If yes, could I have an example as I'm a bit lost on how to do this with a `PagedResultDto<T>` return type?

If not please let me know where I can find out how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically you can, but really shouldn't do sorting in `GetAll()` if it can be avoided. CRUD App Services also define virtual method `ApplySorting()` which is already used by GetAll and can also be overridden.

You can pass the string to dynamically sort by when calling the `GetAll()` and it will already work.

```
await _myAppService.GetAll(new PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto() { Sorting = "Name DESC", MaxResultCount = pageSize, SkipCount = skipCount })
```

---

If you'd like to have more control over sorting behavior, like use something default or pass in better-formatted query strings, override `ApplySorting()`

```
protected override IQueryable<SomeEntity> ApplySorting(IQueryable<SomeEntity> query, PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto input)
{
    var sortBy = "LastModificationTime DESC,CreationTime DESC";

    switch (input.Sorting?.ToLower())
    {
        case "name-asc":
            sortBy = "Name";
            break;

        case "name-desc":
            sortBy = "Name DESC";
            break;
    }

    input.Sorting = sortBy;

    return base.ApplySorting(query, input);
}
```